# Displaying username on index.php

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL table contains the following rows: `Id`, `user_name`, `name` and `password`.  On the login form I require the user to submit `name` and `password` and on submitting the same direct the user to `index.php` page.  After user login I wish to display the value of "user_name" which contains user full name, on the top of `index.php` page.

For example

> Hello : user_name.

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! there are many great tutorials on doing this *exact* thing on the Internet, perhaps you should start with Google.

Comment: any correct complete correct explanation would be too long to be written as an answer. [Here's](http://slunked.com/user-registration-and-login-system/all/1) one tutorial that can help and please next time do something before asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do so (using session,cookies,localstorage etc).
I'll show you a simple way using session;

Let's say that on the top of your page you want have a container for displaying the name, for example :

```
<div class='greet'> Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </header>
```

What you want is to show it only if the user is logged so :

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']): ?>
   <div class='greet'> Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So now, if the user is logged, this div will be created.

When the user is trying to log in (I'm guessing you are posting username and password to a php file and searching for results in a table), if the login is successful you have to add 1 line of code there like this:

```
if(LOGIN SUCCESS CONDITION HERE){
  //SOME CODE
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

Now you can use the variable $_SESSION['username'] to display the username anywhere you wish.

Comment: He clearly stated that he has got to use a database.

Comment: Thanks Anton, Jay, Ashesh and Kristian for responding.  I wish to reiterate my question as I couldn't be able to ask it clearly in my last attempt.  I have a database "deu" and a table "employee"  that table has four rows namely (i) id (ii) user_name (iii) name and (iv) password.  For example the value of these rows are id = 1, user_name= John, name=3042 and password=3042.  Through login page I am matching the name and password i.e. 3042 and 3042 from table and if the user submit it correctly, directing him to index.php. After login I wish to display "Hello John" at the top of lndex.php page

Comment: my login page query is:-                                                                                                 $query = mysql_query("select * from employee where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;

Comment: In the beginning of index.php I put : -                                                                            <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']) {
header('Location: index.php'); 
}
?>

Comment: for printing I am using the following syntex:-    <DIV STYLE="font-family: Arial Black; font-size: 18px; color: white;">
  <?php echo "Hello ".$_SESSION['login_user']; ?>              
  </div>                                                                                                                      Now My index.php page is displaying "Hello 3042 and I wish to display Hello John.

Comment: Well the variable $username is in charge of that. So in this code :
if($rows == 1) { $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $_SESSION['login_user'] = $user['name'];} 
You could assign $user['name'] or $user['user_name'] to the session, whatever you need.

Comment: $rows1 = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$_SESSION['emp_name']=$rows1[1];   Thanks Kristian for your response just solve my problem by inserting the above syntax... thanks again...